# APK build more than 20mb

Tags: android, cordova, build, apk

I created a project on html and I need to build the APK file.
I used phonegap before but now I cannot generate the APK: the size will be larger than than 20 Mb.
Is there another way to compile my project?

Comment: What's wrong with an APK > 20MB ? Compress your assets (e.g. images)

Comment: already compressed everything (have a lot of images)

Comment: try to install it in SD card instead of phone ?

Comment: https://tinypng.com/

Comment: I can not create APK file. Installing is not a problem

Comment: The main amount of pictures are jpg-s. Can tinypng help?

Comment: dont think tinypng supports jpgs, but jpegmini.com i hear is good

Comment: Can you load the images from web server instead ?

Comment: it must work offline

Comment: what is the error when you build it with phonegap ?

Comment: The error is "Maximum size of the app must be lover than 20 Mb"

Answer (score 0):

I have seen APKs that are more than 20 MB, I believe the maximum size supported is 50MB, so you shouldn't worry much about size if yours is less 50MB

Comment: it's about 23 Mb. And i do not need to upload it into market. The problem is with the build creation with phonegap (it supports less than 20 MB files)

Comment: I see, can you compress the images to shrink size?